# Segmentation fault (C++ pointers)

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management

I'm trying to implement a linked list class in C++ using a node class and a pointer to the next node.

```
template<class T>
class Node {
    public: T val;
    public: Node* next;
    public: Node() { }
    public: Node(T val) { this.val = val; } 
};
```

I created a linked list class with a pointer to the head and a function append to add nodes to the list:

```
template<class T>
class LinkedList {
   private: Node<T>* head;

   public: LinkedList() { }
   public: LinkedList(T val) { head -> val = val; }

   public: void append(T val) {
       Node<T>* temp = head;
       while(temp -> val != NULL) {
           temp = temp -> next;
       }
       temp -> val = val;
   }
};
```

but after compilation and running, it throws this error "Segmentation fault (core dumped)"

I know a little about segmentation fault like trying to access a memory location that is no longer existed but I don't get it in this example, any help??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is that you don't initialize the next pointer with null pointer, but you assume it is null pointer by default. Here's how you fix it:

```cpp
template <class T>
class Node {
 public:
  T val;
  Node* next;
  Node( T val_ = {} )
    : val{ val_ }
    , next{ nullptr }
  { }
};
```

Besides that, in the `append` there are problems. Here's how the code should have looked like completely:

```
template <class T>
class Node {
public:
    T val;
    Node* next;
    Node(T val_ = {}) : val{ val_ }, next{ nullptr } {}
};

template <class T>
class LinkedList {
private:
    Node<T>* head;

public:
    LinkedList(T val_ = {}) : head{ new Node{val_} } {}

    void append(T val) {
        Node<T>* temp = head;
        while (temp->next != nullptr) {
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        temp->next = new Node<T>{ val };
    }
};

int main() {
    LinkedList<int> l;
    l.append(10);
}
```

Other comments:

- `this.val` won't compile, because `this` is a pointer. You meant `this->val`.
- You should consider using member [initializer lists](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) instead of `this->val = val`.
- Initialize all members in all constructors.

Comment: thanks for the effort, the error stopped poping up. One more little thing, the next pointer do not hold the value of temp after running append, why is that the case?

Comment: @AbdElrahman That was a mistake on my part. Fixed it. Please see the update.

Comment: Its a simple typo though, it should be temp -> next = new Node<T>{val}; instead of declaring another pointer variable, thanks for the effort again